# Unable to display my list entry on my app [jquery mobile]

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

```
function scan()
{
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            if(!result.cancelled)
            {
                if(result.format == "QR_CODE")
                {
                    var value = result.text;
                    var data = localStorage.getItem("LocalData");
                    console.log(data);
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    data[data.length] = [value];
                    localStorage.setItem("LocalData", JSON.stringify(data));
                    location.reload();
                    appendToList();
                    // location.hash = '#Vote';
                }
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
   );
}
var count = 1;
var listCreated = false;
function appendToList() {            //Create the listview if not created
if(!listCreated){
    $("#content").append("<ul id='list' data-icon = 'true' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-split-icon = 'delete' data-split-theme='a'></ul>");
    listCreated = true;
    $("#content").trigger("create");
            }
    $("#list").append("<li id=count"+count+"><a href=#>" + data[0] + "</a><a href='#delete' data-rel = 'popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop'>Delete</a></li>");  
    $("#list").listview("refresh")
    count ++;
        }
```

Is something wrong with my code? I'm trying to output the newest data from my array onto my list. I've tried scanning a QR code countless of times, but it's not working. I want to scan a QR code with text, and then use that text as a new entry in listview.

Comment: you invoked `location.reload();` before `appendToList();` witch reload your page.

Comment: #2 data is not defined globaly get

Comment: yes, i realized about the location.reload(). However, I'm finding a big problem when I'm trying to scan other QR codes. Im trying to get like 50.001, 50.002 and 50.003 as list elements, but it just keeps repeating the same 50.001 once it's scanned once. How do i fix that?

Comment: Yes, thats because you didn't use for loop. check answer below

Comment: the 50.001 text is always repeating i don't know why. i tried clearing local storage, and clearing data array at the end but not working. (yeah, for loop still happening same problem)

Comment: error is still there after change. I think it's stuck at constantly accessing the same index.

Comment: See code updates, there was another error that because `localStorage["LocalData"]` returns `null` and you cant push items to null. and fixed now.

Comment: Hmm. Error still persists. I'm checking for a 50.009 text QR code, but it keeps giving me a 50.005 (old one). I cleared the localStorage and tried again, but same problem. It just keeps printing the same value.

Comment: you mean that only one list item displayed `50.009`

Comment: Yes! Also, there is a typo in your code. `if(!localStorage.getItem("LocalData"))localStorage.setItem("LocalData","[]")`

Comment: what is `console.log(data);` display?

Comment: code is right `if(statement)do_some_thing`

Comment: I can't check console.log because I'm using this on my phone.

Comment: It says "50.005, 50.005, 50.009, 50.009, 50.009, 50.009, 50.009, 50.009" I think it's stuck on the first index and not moving. Ideally it should be a single element which i can just call.

Comment: Did you scan 2 Qrcode's?  50.005, 50.009 are the text of qrcode you capature

Comment: Yes. I scanned 2 different QR codes.

Comment: So code working and no error, but you want to use number increased every time to display in your list

Comment: Yes, so say I take my phone to scan 1 QR code. I get 1 number 50.001. I add that number to my list view. Then I take my phone and scan another QR code. I get 1 number 50.002. I add that number to my list view and so on.

Comment: so there is max number 50.001 to 50.999 then 51.001 to 51.999 .. etc

Comment: check code update.

Comment: I don't intend on having max number, it can be any number! from 3.007 to 50.001 to 105.512! Any number is fine!

Comment: Oh man. Now when I scan, I get all the values from .001 to 018

Comment: Is that not Ok? the array loop reversed.

Comment: Now you have `href='#details0'`, `href='#details1'`, `href='#details2'` to be easy if you have page sliding to view details

Comment: No no. My goal is to scan 1 QR code, and get 1 element on my ListView. At any time, I will scan 1 QR code. I will take the text from the QR code and then add it as a new element on my ListView

Comment: you should need to add some data for every qrcode like date & text...?

Comment: No, just a plain text. No data. Just text. I just need to scan a QR code, get the text on it, and create 1 item in the listview with that element. And keep doing it if i have more qr code

Comment: So is there any problems now? where do you want to display text's? all your data listed as numbers?

Comment: Yes. I don't need a for loop! Now when I scan one qr code i get 20 numbers!! I only want to get 1 number when I scan one qr code!

Comment: Yep, your question code said that you want to store the data locally ? so you want to display last captured QR

Comment: Yes,only  want to display last captured QR nothing else

Comment: Try code now...

Comment: There is no output now.

Comment: should work, try now

Comment: any error displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by implementing a reset function to reset my local storage data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data; //this should be global variable
    function scan() {
      cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result) {
          if (!result.cancelled) {
            if (result.format == "QR_CODE") {
              var value = result.text;
              if(!localStorage.getItem("LocalData"))localStorage.setItem("LocalData","[]")
              data = localStorage.getItem("LocalData");
              //alert(data);
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              data.push(value);
              localStorage.setItem("LocalData", JSON.stringify(data));
              //why you need to refresh page next line
              //location.reload();
              appendToList();
              // location.hash = '#Vote';
            }
          }
        },
        function(error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
      );
    }


    function appendToList() { //Create the listview if not created
      if (!$("#content").length) {
        $("#content").append("<ul id='list' data-icon='true' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-split-icon='delete' data-split-theme='a'></ul>");
        $("#content").trigger("create");
      }
        var nveiw = 3 + ((+data.length+1)/1000);
        $("#list").append("<li id='count" + data.length + "'><a href='#details="+(+data.length-1)+"'>" + nveiw + "</a><a href='#delete' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop'>Delete</a></li>");

      $("#list").listview("refresh");
    }
```